# Is fixed Functions supported in newer android devices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am wondering whether if using Fixed Functions in OpenGL will work on newer Android devices. I couldnt find any solid information about this on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed Functions are supported for `OpenGL <= 3.0` and `OpenGL ES <= 1.x`. They are not supported on later versions.

Check what is available on your newer Android device.

See official information for more details.

[OpenGL ES.](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/2_X/)

[OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline)